# Can an ASP.NET MVC PartialView have a _Layout

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-layout

Can an ASP.NET MVC **PartialView** directly use a **Layout**?

### MSDN

I have looked at MSDN for [`PartialViewResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and compared with [`ViewResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

`ViewResult` has a property [**`MasterName`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult.mastername%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that `PartialViewResult` does not.

But.. I can still define the `Layout` property in the partial views Razor.

### Background

I am currently remediating a large code base with a huge amount of partial views used to fill iframes. Ideally they would be converted to normal views (ideally we would not use iframes) but I was wondering about just adding a layout to these partials to take out the `<head>` element at least so that we have more control over the script versioning (everything is replicated in each partial view). I'm looking for a light-touch solution since much of the code is expected to be thrown away.

Comment: If you're rendering these in an iframe instead of as child actions, shouldn't they be invoked as Views anyway, instead of PartialViews?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - you are right, but that would be a more invasive change. Our goal, for now, is to get a handle on the many versions of jQuery (jQueryUI, etc) used throughout the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, even in `Partial View` also we can set `Layout` property which turns `Partial View` as normal `View` with `Layout`.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use a layout within a layout:

Layout
 View
   Layout
     PartialView

We have an example of this in our codebase.